# resume serverless azure database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to automate a serverless azure database to be online during set hours and then paused "off hours".

Is there a way to do this using PowerShell commands or another automated way to put it online starting at a specific time during the work week?

Right now using the autopause option, but the main issue is that it requires an initial database hit to put the database online, which causes too long of a down time between the first database hit to the database being online and usable by the application. Thanks

Comment: what's the desired behavior if the database is hit during off hours?

Comment: Did you open **Auto-pause delay**:
The database automatically pauses if it is inactive for the time period specified here, and automatically resumes when database activity recurs. Alternatively, auto-pausing can be disabled.?

Comment: @DerekGusoff Off hours I would prefer to have it behave like a normal autopause based on a set time and in and idle state unless hit... off hours that's acceptable... but if it needs to be offline off hours to be automated that's fine also.

Comment: @LeonYue Can that be done in an automated or PowerShell method? I can setup the Auto-pause delay manually but would need an automated way to disable it during normal business hours.

Comment: I did just find the PowerShell command Set-AzSqlDatabase which has an option to set the AutoPauseDelayInMinutes... I'm now wondering if that would be the best way (or at least a way) to enable and disable that feature in an automated way for the server db instance to be instantly available during normal hours and then having autopause enabled during off hours? (sorry I'm not in a location to be able to test this right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got REST API call to pause Azure SQL database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/Databases/Pause

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333- 
444444444444/resourceGroups/Default-SQL- 
SouthEastAsia/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/
testsvr/databases/testdwdb/pause?api-version=2019-06-01-preview
```

Similarly, you can resume the Azure SQL Database, using REST API call

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/resume

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId} 
/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/ 
databases/{databaseName}/resume?api-version=2019-06-01-preview
```

You can set up automated calls as specific times to pause and resume.
You can leverage `Invoke-RestMethod`[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7) in Powershell to call the rest method.

Comment: These api calls would work on a serverless azure database instance? (apologies for the double-confirmation)

Comment: @mgalpy, No problem. yes. they will.

Comment: I think a better question would be: Would this api calls work on a NON serverless db?

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell command Set-AzSqlDatabase which has an option to set the AutoPauseDelayInMinutes for a serverless azure database might to be an option to automate this process.

Set the AutoPauseDelayInMinutes to -1 to opt out during normal business hours and then to the desired value prior to off hours.

Answer (score 0):

As pause and resume commands have not implemented yet on Serverless edition of Azure SQL Database, for resume you can just open a connection to it using a simple powershell

```
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connectionString
$sqlConnection.Open()
```

By setting ConnectTimeout and also doing [retry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45472343/6333454) you can ensure the Database is online before making your actual connection from the application/service.

Comment: According the the REST API calls answered by @VenkataramanR the commands are available?