# Automatically trigger Azure SQL database to be "online"

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am using an Azure Serverless SQL database that goes to a "paused" state after 2 hours - this is all working as "auto-pause" is enabled (this I don't want to change).

[image: Azure Auto Pause]

Is it possible to somehow automatically trigger the SQL database to be "online" say once a day for when the application end-user start work in the morning so they not having to wait for the database to become 'on-line'?

Comment: certain events can bring the database "online" , for example  taking a backup. Maybe i can creat an automation task to do this. Not sure how to create; an automation account, run book , schedule and power-shell  script that takes a database backup yet. I would like to create these Azure services via the azure az module....

Comment: Going to try and use a Azure function that just connects to the database as this will forc eit online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql#auto-resuming),

> Auto-resuming can be triggered if any of the below conditions are true:
>
> - Authentication and authorization
> - Threat detection
> - Data discovery and classification
> - Auditing
> - Data masking
> - Transparent data encryption
> - Vulnerability assessment
> - Query (performance) data store
> - Performance recommendations
> - Auto-tuning
> - Database copying
> - SQL data sync
> - Modifying certain database metadata
> - SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

You can automatically trigger the azure serverless SQL database to be “**online**” if you trigger the any of the above conditions daily.
**Viewing auditing records, updating or viewing auditing policy** can trigger the auto-resume of the database.
The `Get-AzSqlDatabaseAudit` can be used for that. Please check the Powershell script below which is referred from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqldatabaseaudit?view=azps-8.0.0).

```
Get-AzSqlDatabaseAudit
[-ResourceGroupName] <String>
[-ServerName] <String>
[-DatabaseName] <String>
[-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
[<CommonParameters>]
```

If you automate the above script to run daily, you can achieve your requirement.
Please go through this [Article by Salaudeen Rajack on sharepointdiary](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/11/sharepoint-online-schedule-powershell-script-using-azure-automation.html) to check the process of **automating the Powershell script**.

Also, you can auto-resume the database by **creating the backup of your database**.
Please go through this [Official blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/automate-exporting-of-azure-sql-database-as-bacpac-to-blog/ba-p/2409213) to **Automate the exporting of azure SQL database as .bacpac** to blob storage.

Please refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345506/resume-serverless-azure-database?rq=1) to check various approaches other than these.

Comment: I created an Azure automation account and scheduled job that just quried the 'audit data' of the database - this action triggers the Azure SQL to come 'online'. Thanks for your advice.