# copy file to Azure File Share (Azure Storage)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-vm-scale-set

in addition to my question [Code sync from Azure Scale Set VM To Azure Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64881572/code-sync-from-azure-scale-set-vm-to-azure-storage) is there any way to copy files from one of the particular Scale Set VM to Azure File share(Azure Storage) through ADO Pipelines ? since its scale Set server i cant push every time from one VM. Eg: In pool there will be 100 VMSS servers ,when i try to push code through pipeline it should pick up one server from pool and from that need to push code !!!  does it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No, we do not have this kind of build-in task. We have a [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops) which use it copy application files and other artifacts to Microsoft Azure storage blobs or virtual machines (VMs).

> When the target is Azure VMs, the files are first copied to an
> automatically generated Azure blob container and then downloaded into
> the VMs. The container is deleted after the files have been
> successfully copied to the VMs.

As a workaround, please use a custom script to copy files to Azure File Storage. In other words, if you are able to do the same thing locally. You should also be able to achieve it through Azure DevOps pipeline.

You may have to built your own extension or use scripts in pipeline. Take a look at this similar 3rd-party task-- [AzureDevOpsReleaseToFileStorage](https://github.com/kunalchandratre1/AzureDevOpsReleaseToFileStorage)